# Sending bcc email to recipient using shell script mail utility

Tags: shell, sh

I am using shell script and using below mail utility to send email.

```
mail -s "Data Missing report" "normalUser@test.net" < /opt/emailscript/fileToSend.txt
```

Above script is working fine, how can i add some other user (for e.g. bccuser@test.net) in the list that can automatically be bcc'd using same utility/command?

Comment: Doesn't  -b bccuser@test.net  work?

Comment: There are many `mail` implementations, maybe some of them don't support `-b`?  But we can't really help unless you can tell us which platform you're on and which version of `mail` you're using. It's unfortunate that there isn't just one.

Comment: have you checked the mail manpage on your server whether it supports bcc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MAIL(1)                   BSD General Commands Manual                  MAIL(1)

NAME
     mail - send and receive mail

SYNOPSIS
     mail [-iInv] [-s subject] [-c cc-addr] [-b bcc-addr] to-addr... [-- sendmail-options...]
     mail [-iInNv] -f [name]
     mail [-iInNv] [-u user]
 -c    Send carbon copies to list of users.
 -b    Send blind carbon copies to list.  List should be a comma-separated list of names.
```

The command is(I have tested it on CentOS6.x):

```
 echo -e "body" | mail  -S smtp=localhost -s "Test subject 1"  -b bccuser@gmail.com user@gmail.com
```

The `to-addr` is after `cc-addr` and `bcc-addr`

Comment: That last comment that the "to-addr" must come after the "cc/bcc" is absolutely crucial!